# c# Add As Link not working (always copies to Project folder?)

Tags: c#, file, hyperlink

c# VS2008 SP1

right Click on Project name, Add Existing Item, selecting Add As Link from the drop down menu, and selecting a .cs file outside of the project folder, causes the file to be copied locally within the project folder.

This is surely not the correct behavior?

Comment: Is it a file that already exists elsewhere in the open solution?

Answer (score 3):

Right Click on Project name, Add Existing Item, selecting a .cs file outside of the project folder **AND THEN** Add As Link from the drop down menu.

Answer (score 0):

That is the default behavior. Also confirmed with Visual Studio 2010

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't do that for me.  Are you selecting the file you want first, and then selecting "Add as link" in the weird dropdown button?

Comment: Yes. It copies the file to the project folder and in its Properties is a grayed-out link to the local file I cannot edit

Comment: Solved: I restarted visual studio a few times and now its working OK. must have been a glitch